# React and Emoji-Mart onClickOutside weird issue

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I wanted to create a emoji picker for my project. But I ran into this weird issue when implementing `onClickOutside`. Whenever you click the "<input type="image"..." for the first time, the picker gets successfully shown. After it is closed, you cannot open it anymore. I have figured out why it will not open anymore, but not why it is behaving like that.

It doesn't open anymore because:
First `handleEmojiClick` is run, then `handleClickOutside`.
`handleClickOutside` should not even happen in the first place since it is not rendered at the time.
Console logs the following order of method calls (these are the first 4 clicks on the input type image:

```
running emoji click
running emoji click
running outside click
running emoji click
running outside click
```

This is the full code:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import emojiPickerIcon from "../../assets/emojiPicker.png";
import emojiPickerPickedIcon from "../../assets/emojiPickerPicked.png";
import Picker from '@emoji-mart/react';


export default function DebugPage() {

    const [emojiPickerShown, setEmojiPickerShown] = useState(false);


    function handleClickOutside(e){
        if(emojiPickerShown){
            setEmojiPickerShown(false);
        }
    }


    function handleEmojiClick(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        setEmojiPickerShown(!emojiPickerShown)
    }

    return (
        <form>
            <input type="image" src={emojiPickerShown ? emojiPickerPickedIcon : emojiPickerIcon} onClick={handleEmojiClick} />
            { emojiPickerShown && <Picker onClickOutside={handleClickOutside} /> } 
        </form>
    )
}
```

This is very odd behavior since that function should not run while the picker is not even rendered.

I tried a lot of debugging, getting it out the form, scaling down the code size, heck this is even a debug page.

Answer (score 1):

You need to stop the click event from propagating to the `Picker` component using [`Event.stopPropagation()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation).

Here is a simplified and working version:

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import Picker from '@emoji-mart/react';

const emojiPickerIcon = 'https://picsum.photos/50/50';

const DebugPage = () => {
    const [show, setShow] = useState(false);

    return (
        <>
            <input
                type='image'
                src={emojiPickerIcon}
                onClick={(event) => {
                    event.stopPropagation(); // <=== CRITIAL LINE HERE
                    setShow((show) => {
                        return !show;
                    });
                }}
                alt={'emoji picker'}
            />
            {show ? (
                <Picker
                    onClickOutside={() => {
                        setShow(false);
                    }}
                />
            ) : null}
        </>
    );
};

export default DebugPage;
```

Comment: Hi, thankyou for your comment. I had found this aswell, this works as a solution but my question was mainly meant, to ask for why this behaviour is happening, because the Picker is not even rendered (I shouldn't have to stop propogating when the element is not even in the dom) to the screen when the bug occurs. This must be a bug in Emoji-Mart right?

Comment: Seems like it. I don't know a lot about event propagation, and it does seem like it shouldn't be rendered in your case.

Comment: Yes I strongly suggest it is a bug in Emoji-Mart, I have opened up an issue on github. It happens while not rendered, I've looked a bit at the source code and I think there must be a bug with their unregister (this removes the eventListener from window obj) function.